# programmatically position a EditText component in android?

Tags: android

how do i position an edit text dynamically at runtime in android?

followig is my code:

```
public class ABCActivity extends Activity   {
  EditText ed;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ed = new EditText(ABCActivity.this);
    ed.setEnabled(false);    
    layout =new LinearLayout(this);  
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f);            
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn = new Button(this); 
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn.setText("Change");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ed.getLayoutParams();
    params2.leftMargin = 10;
    params2.topMargin = 10;
    ed.setLayoutParams(params2);

    layout.addView(btn);   
    layout.addView(ed);

   }    
}
```

Gives Force close at :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ed.getLayoutParams();
```

error: Null pointer Exception
i tried using relative layout .....
but does not work

Comment: What you want. Please give brief information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial on this by Lars Vogel [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/03/14/android-hacking-layouts/). Basically you have to use the LayoutParams specific to your layout to position views through Java.

Comment: Thanks Raghav thats really a very nice tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Your can set position of your `EditText` this way, I have give it dummy values of 10, 10.

```
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ed.getLayoutParams();
         params.leftMargin = 10;
         params.topMargin = 10;
         ed.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I am already using linear layout . how do i use relative layout along with linear layout will sum1 plz let me kno it gives me force close when i try using relative layout.

Comment: If parent of your control is `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` then use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Aqif